# How can I add table with javascript to a html page here is my trying

Tags: javascript, html

```
function generateTable() {
    const table = document.createElement("table")
    table.classList.add("table", "table-striped")
    const thead = document.createElement("thead")
    const tr = document.createElement("tr")
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody")

    const titles = [
      "Name",
      "Manufacturer",
      "Type",
      "Packaging",
      "Quantity",
      "Price",
    ];

    for(const title of titles){
        const th = document.createElement("th")
        th.innerText = title
        tr.append(th)
        thead.append(tr)
        table.append(thead)

    }
    table.append(tbody)


for (const prod of products) {
  const tr = generateRow(tea)
  tbody.appendChild(tr)
}
return table
}
```

I want it for my exampe, but need some fetch api.

So this code actually works but I dont understand everything.

I dont understand the for loops work. Can somebody explaine it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Use that website for the rest of your questions like this - it's what the rest of us are using for questions like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it by steps:
Here, you are defining some variables, indicating that each one of them will contain an HTML tag.

```
const table = document.createElement("table") //equals a table
const thead = document.createElement("thead") //equal a thead tag (header)
const tr = document.createElement("tr") //equals a table row
```

And here:

```
table.classList.add("table", "table-striped") //you add the class 'table' and 'table-striped' appended to your constant table.
```

In structured programming, a loop is a way to perform certain actions until the condition is satisfied.
In this case, use the loop on your `titles` array to loop through as follows:

```
for(const title of titles)
```

From this moment on, the `title` constant is created, which takes only the specific position of one of the elements within `titles`, that is, in your first title it will be equal a `titles[0]` or having a more specific value, will be `"name"`.
(Note that each time it enters the loop, the value will change and move on to the next position.)

After this for each array element, you do the following process:

```
    const th = document.createElement("th") //creates the column title element (th)
    th.innerText = title //this is the text contained within the th, which is the value within the titles array
    tr.append(th) //assign your th to the table row
    thead.append(tr) //assign your tr to thead
    table.append(thead) //assign your thead to the html table
```

If this was not done, you would need to repeat your code once for each element, changing only the `title` to the field name.
In sequence the same happens with other variables that were not fully defined in this example code. The explanation is the same for all. And at the end of the function, you return your table.

If you want to go deeper into the content, I recommend reading these links, which will explain the process in detail and with an example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp